# Weird null pointer exception when trying to access a StackPane JAVA

Tags: java, javafx, nullpointerexception

I am receiving a null pointer exception and I am not sure why. I have this function that is called when a button is pressed:

```
@FXML
private void handlePlayButton(ActionEvent e) {

    for(Node child:getCenterPaneUndirectedNonWeightedGraph().getChildren()) {
        if(child instanceof StackPane) {
            StackPane vertex = (StackPane) child;
            System.out.println(vertex == null);
            bfs.fillVertexTransition(vertex);
        }
    }

}
```

My print statement 'System.out.println(vertex == null);' prints false.

I get the null pointer exception at the line:

```
bfs.fillVertexTransition(vertex);
```

The method 'fillVertexTransition' is defined by:

```
public void fillVertexTransition(StackPane vertex) {
    Circle circle = (Circle) vertex.getChildren().get(0);

    FillTransition ft = new FillTransition(Duration.millis(3000), circle, Color.RED, Color.BLUE);
    ft.play();

}
```

In my application the StackPanes are circles with a label on top of the circle.

Any way I can fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: it might be that bfs is null. it might be that something within that method throws the NPE. look at the stacktrace and figure out what line throws the Exception firstµ

Comment: Yup thats it I forgot to initialise the bfs object *FacePalm*. Thank you